# Multichain token: Claim erc20 on L2 requiring balance of erc721 on Mainnet

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, polygon, bridge, arbitrum

So, I'm working on an NFT project on mainnet and we want it to have its own currency on L2 so its actually a frictionless currency.

We are looking into Arbitrum and Polygon.
I've noticed that first you have to deploy to L1 then to L2 if you want assets to be bridgeable.

First issue is how to allow for minting on a L2 and call balanceOf() on L1.
Going through Polygon's docs, I found a way to communicate between polygon and mainnet: https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/mintable-assets
It seems like that's how CoolCats are implementing their $Gold token which is on Polygon. So my question is, do you know of any contract that does this and that you could share? CC's contract is still undisclosed.

Second issue is: when generating daily revenue of a certain erc20 for each NFT, should the NFT itself estimate how much each NFT is allowed to mint erc20s or should the erc20 contract contain verify? Or should a third contract keep track of claims?